Rig Deforming a Mesh that has no weights applied to it
Body and Head are two separate meshes which I connected to one rig, but the right and middle of the body rig deforms the head, which has no weights applied to any part of the head. I deleted all the vertex groups of the body part of the mesh, so I don't know why the lower parts deform the head. The head worked fine before I attached the lower rig to it.
I'll even attach the blend file to this post.

[
It could be because of a vertex group of the mouth, but I doubt it:

The head moves when body bones are moved, even though no weight has been applied to it:


Please edit your question and add the full link into it rather than putting it in a comment where it may be missed and possibly deleted!

The issue is that your "muzzle" mesh, which your head mesh is shrinkwarped on, is bound to your bones. So when you rotate the bone, they don't affect the head mesh, but the muzzle mesh, which in turn affects the head mesh via the shrinkwarp.
To be honest I am unsure of why you even have that shrinkwarp system. But a better solution could be to parent the muzzle object to the bone, instead of parenting it via the armature deform modifier using weights.
So first, unhide your muzzle object to be able to edit it. ↹ Tab into edit mode, select all your mesh with A, and in the Vertex Groups panel select the Head group and hit Remove:

↹ Tab into object mode, select your muzzle object then ⇧ Shift select your armature, ↹ Tab into pose mode, select the head bone, and press ⎈ CtrlP > Set Parent To Bone:

You can then remove all the armature modifiers from your muzzle object (you already have one dead from previous work, might as well tidy things up).
Result:


Thank you for taking time out of your day to help me, I really appreciate that.                                                      The reason why I have the muzzle mesh underneath the head is to be able to change the mouth position on the head without  changing the form of the whole head.

@BigTuggz if the answer is correct, please mark it as such

@BigTuggz in that case you should probably remove the thickness around the lips in your nesh, and let the solidify modifier handle making your mesh thick for you. Shrinkwrap modifiers don't handle very well anything beyond a simple "layer" of mesh.
